# How to create a Facebook Like Counter for a page on my website?

Tags: html, facebook, coldfusion

I want to create a Facebook like counter for specific pages on my website.

For example I may have these pages on my website, of which, each have a different article on them:

```
www.mysite.com/article1.cfm

www.mysite.com/article2.cfm

www.mysite.com/article3.cfm
```

I want each of these pages to have its own Facebook "like" counter element which when clicked will keep track of how many likes that individual page has. I've tried to check out Facebook's explanation of all of this, but I'm new to Facebook development. My primary server-side language I must use to accomplish this is ColdFusion - of course if there is a JavaScript/jQuery solution or other ways to accomplish this I am open.

Comment: It looks like I will have to automate completing their Facebook like form? This code needs to be a reusable element in which I can just put on a template. This way, the Facebook like counter will dynamically be set up for a new page built off the template. Sorry I didn't specify this earlier.

Comment: I suggest getting it to work with a single page first and then converting the code to something re-useable.  You can use cfhttp to post data to forms.

Comment: In this code:

js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=**myappid**"

It doesn't seem to like the first and second = symbols within the quotations

Answer (score 4):

This is how you'd add facebook like to your pages:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.yourwebsite.com" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where:

- YOUR_APP_ID: Must be an application ID you can create by having a facebook developer account. you can create one by going [here](http://developers.facebook.com/)
- http://www.yourwebsite.com: Is the URL to your website. because
  facebook like actually posts to your timeline, this is going to be
  the link to it

Comment: Okay I have taken that code and worked with it. Here is my current script:

Comment: <cfoutput>
 <script src="/common/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <cfset currentURL = "#CGI.SERVER_NAME#" & "#CGI.PATH_INFO#">
 
 <script>
  $('html').attr('xmlns:fb', 'http://ogp.me/ns/fb#');
 </script>
 
 <div id="fb-root"></div>

Comment: <script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=537981986220630";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
 </script>

 <div class="fb-like" data-href="#currentURL#" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
</cfoutput>

Comment: I'm getting some errors though...
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

=

The CFML compiler was processing:

    An expression that began on line 17, column 64.
    The expression might be missing an ending #, for example, #expr instead of #expr#.
    An expression beginning with \', on line 7, column 65.This message is usually caused by a problem in the expressions structure.
    The body of a cfoutput tag beginning on line 1, column 2.

Comment: Hey @user1955504 post the code you've written into your question, so I can copy it and fix it.

Comment: @user1955504 until you post your actual code in a more readable way, it will be hard for me to help you, but what I can tell you, is that you're getting errors because ColdFusioin uses #'s to identify variables. Replace all your non-coldfusion variables that have one # to have two like "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=537981986220630" becomes "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js##xfbml=1&appId=537981986220630" and it will render

Answer (score 2):

All infortmation you need here. Very simple form to create and customise your like button.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

- You will need to go through this once for every page. Then click "get code" and copy and paste what FB gives you into your relevant web page.