# Is it possible to access public Facebook page data (e.g. total number of likes) without OAuth access token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

I want Facebook page likes counter to be visible on my Wordpress website.
Until around a week ago (mid June 2015) the following PHP code did the job:

```
<?php
    ...
    $params = array(
        'sslverify' => false,
        'timeout'   => 60
    );
    $api_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/';
    $this->connection = wp_remote_get( $api_url . $facebook_page_id, $params );
    ...
    /* if error then use cached data */
    ...
?>
```

but something seems to have changed, as it does not work any more.

I tried querying Facebook Graph API with "https://graph.facebook.com/page_id", but it returns an authentication error:

```
{"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104}}
```

As far as I understand, there is no need in access token for public data.

How do I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to generate a token for your application/code to use. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens . funny if your code worked this long without one.  You may have had a plugin or something that generated one for you, but it has expired (access tokens may need to be renewed every 90 days or so)

edit: this is a similar question [How to create a Facebook Like Counter for a page on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199747/how-to-create-a-facebook-like-counter-for-a-page-on-my-website)

Comment: App Access Tokens don't expire! With the deprecation of the Graph API v1.0, Access Tokens need to be added to nearly all requests.

Comment: @Tobi could you please provide a source to confirm this change in the Graph API?

Comment: What change? Use `{app_id}|{app_secret}` as App Access Token, as outlined in the last paragrpahs ofhttps://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens Unless you change your app secret, this will work eternally with the current Graph API

Comment: I call it a `change` simply because the code worked before ;) So I am trying to figure out, what is the reason for it. The code did not contain app access token, but you are right - according to the API documentation - it should.